# build failed when trying to instal OpenCV-iOS cocoapod

Tags: ios, opencv, terminal, cocoapods

I an trying to install the OpenCV-iOS cocoapod. When I ran pod install it give me a big error message.

Error Message: (part of it)

```
Trying OpenCV-iOS
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
mkdir build-iphoneos
cd build-iphoneos
cmake -GXcode -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_MACOSX_BUNDLE=ON -DCMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO -DAPPLE_FRAMEWORK=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/ios/cmake/Toolchains/Toolchain-iPhoneOS_Xcode.cmake -DENABLE_NEON=ON ../
xcodebuild -arch armv7 -arch armv7s -arch arm64 -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release -parallelizeTargets -jobs 4 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -target ALL_BUILD build OTHER_CFLAGS="$(inherited) -Wno-implicit-function-declaration"
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install -P cmake_install.cmake
mkdir ../build-iphonesimulator
cd ../build-iphonesimulator
cmake -GXcode -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_MACOSX_BUNDLE=ON -DCMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO -DAPPLE_FRAMEWORK=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/ios/cmake/Toolchains/Toolchain-iPhoneSimulator_Xcode.cmake ../
xcodebuild -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release -parallelizeTargets -jobs 4 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -target ALL_BUILD build OTHER_CFLAGS="$(inherited) -Wno-implicit-function-declaration"
mv ../build-iphoneos/install/ ../
cd ../install
lipo -create lib/libopencv_world.dylib ../build-iphonesimulator/lib/Release/libopencv_world.dylib -output lib/libopencv2.dylib
install_name_tool -id @rpath/libopencv2.dylib lib/libopencv2.dylib

-- Setting up iPhoneOS toolchain
-- iPhoneOS toolchain loaded
-- Setting up iPhoneOS toolchain
-- iPhoneOS toolchain loaded
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 9.0.0.9000039
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 9.0.0.9000039
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - failed
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR

 ...

-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- FP16: Compiler support is not available
-- Looking for fseeko
-- Looking for fseeko - not found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - not found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - not found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - not found
-- Check size of off64_t
-- Check size of off64_t - failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32 - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ATTRIBUTES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ATTRIBUTES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
 ...
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.1.0-dev =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2018-01-17T00:03:59Z
--     Host:                        Darwin 17.3.0 x86_64
--     Target:                      iOS
--     CMake:                       3.10.1
--     CMake generator:             Xcode
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/xcodebuild
--     Xcode:                       9.2
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++  (ver 9.0.0.9000039)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-unused-function -Wno-overloaded-virtual   -DNDEBUG -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-unused-function -Wno-overloaded-virtual   -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
--     C flags (Release):           -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          -framework Accelerate -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework QuartzCore -framework AssetsLibrary -framework UIKit
--     3rdparty dependencies:       libjpeg libpng zlib
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml photo video imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect features2d calib3d stitching videostab world
--     Disabled:                    -
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python2 superres ts viz
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     Cocoa:                       YES
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
--     WEBP:                        NO
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.19)
--     TIFF:                        NO
--     JPEG 2000:                   NO
--     OpenEXR:                     NO
--     GDAL:                        NO
--     GDCM:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     AVFoundation:                YES
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     QuickTime:                   NO
--     QTKit:                       NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/NO
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            GCD
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Lapack:                  NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  NO
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 NO
-- 
--   Python (for build):            NO
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:                        NO
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     NO
--     PlantUML:                    NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       NO
--     Performance tests:           NO
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO
-- 
--   Install path:                  /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/install
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos
User defaults from command line:
    IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks = 4

Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO
    OTHER_CFLAGS =  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration
    SDKROOT = iphoneos11.2

Build Preparation
Build task concurrency set to 4 via user default IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks

=== BUILD AGGREGATE TARGET ZERO_CHECK OF PROJECT OpenCV WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
warning: iOS 11.2.0 does not support armv7
warning: iOS 11.2.0 does not support armv7s

Write auxiliary files
write-file /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/ZERO_CHECK.build/Script-7DAC25DC952F47CE8C67268C.sh
chmod 0755 /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/ZERO_CHECK.build/Script-7DAC25DC952F47CE8C67268C.sh

PhaseScriptExecution CMake\ Rules /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/ZERO_CHECK.build/Script-7DAC25DC952F47CE8C67268C.sh
    cd /var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS
    /bin/sh -c /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/ZERO_CHECK.build/Script-7DAC25DC952F47CE8C67268C.sh
echo ""

make -f /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/CMakeScripts/ReRunCMake.make
make[1]: `/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache' is up to date.

=== BUILD TARGET zlib OF PROJECT OpenCV WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
Check dependencies
warning: iOS 11.2.0 does not support armv7
warning: iOS 11.2.0 does not support armv7s

Write auxiliary files
/bin/mkdir -p /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/arm64
write-file /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/zlib.LinkFileList
/bin/mkdir -p /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7
write-file /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/zlib.LinkFileList
/bin/mkdir -p /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7s
write-file /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/zlib.LinkFileList

CompileC /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/adler32.o 3rdparty/zlib/adler32.c normal armv7 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O3 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wno-non-literal-null-conversion -Wno-objc-literal-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -DCMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release-iphoneos\" -DNO_FSEEKO -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=11.2 -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -Wno-comma -Wno-block-capture-autoreleasing -Wno-strict-prototypes -fembed-bitcode-marker -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/lib/Release/include -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/3rdparty/zlib -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/DerivedSources -Wmost -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-unknown-pragmas -F/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/lib/Release -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/adler32.d --serialize-diagnostics /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/adler32.dia -c /var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/3rdparty/zlib/adler32.c -o /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/adler32.o
clang: error: invalid iOS deployment version '-miphoneos-version-min=11.2', iOS 10 is the maximum deployment target for 32-bit targets [-Winvalid-ios-deployment-target]

CompileC /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/compress.o 3rdparty/zlib/compress.c normal armv7 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O3 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wno-non-literal-null-conversion -Wno-objc-literal-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -DCMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release-iphoneos\" -DNO_FSEEKO -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=11.2 -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -Wno-comma -Wno-block-capture-autoreleasing -Wno-strict-prototypes -fembed-bitcode-marker -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/lib/Release/include -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/3rdparty/zlib -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/DerivedSources -Wmost -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-unknown-pragmas -F/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/lib/Release -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/compress.d --serialize-diagnostics /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/compress.dia -c /var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/3rdparty/zlib/compress.c -o /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/compress.o
clang: error: invalid iOS deployment version '-miphoneos-version-min=11.2', iOS 10 is the maximum deployment target for 32-bit targets [-Winvalid-ios-deployment-target]

CompileC /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/crc32.o 3rdparty/zlib/crc32.c normal armv7 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O3 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wno-non-literal-null-conversion -Wno-objc-literal-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -DCMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release-iphoneos\" -DNO_FSEEKO -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=11.2 -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -Wno-comma -Wno-block-capture-autoreleasing -Wno-strict-prototypes -fembed-bitcode-marker -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/lib/Release/include -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/3rdparty/zlib -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/DerivedSources -Wmost -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-unknown-pragmas -F/private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/lib/Release -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/crc32.d --serialize-diagnostics /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/crc32.dia -c /var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/3rdparty/zlib/crc32.c -o /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/crc32.o
clang: error: invalid iOS deployment version '-miphoneos-version-min=11.2', iOS 10 is the maximum deployment target for 32-bit targets [-Winvalid-ios-deployment-target]

CompileC /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/deflate.o 3rdparty/zlib/deflate.c normal armv7 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

 ...

=== BUILD TARGET libjpeg OF PROJECT OpenCV WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
Check dependencies
warning: iOS 11.2.0 does not support armv7
warning: iOS 11.2.0 does not support armv7s

Write auxiliary files
/bin/mkdir -p /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/libjpeg/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/libjpeg.build/Objects-normal/armv7
write-file /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/libjpeg/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/libjpeg.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libjpeg.LinkFileList
/bin/mkdir -p /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/libjpeg/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/libjpeg.build/Objects-normal/armv7s
write-file /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/libjpeg/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/libjpeg.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/libjpeg.LinkFileList
/bin/mkdir -p /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/libjpeg/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/libjpeg.build/Objects-normal/arm64
write-file /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/libjpeg/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/libjpeg.build/Objects-normal/arm64/libjpeg.LinkFileList

CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:72 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0020 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:76 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0022 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:81 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


/bin/bash: line 5: inherited: command not found
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/adler32.o 3rdparty/zlib/adler32.c normal armv7 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/compress.o 3rdparty/zlib/compress.c normal armv7 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/crc32.o 3rdparty/zlib/crc32.c normal armv7 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /private/var/folders/lb/2_dfvxbj1bz6jl33bdhktfy40000gq/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenCV-iOS/build-iphoneos/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/zlib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/deflate.o 3rdparty/zlib/deflate.c normal armv7 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(4 failures)
```

I have installed make using the CMake installer and then install the command line tools by pasting this in terminal  `sudo "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui" --install`. I have also run the `Xcode-select --install` command. I am staring to believe that the there is something wrong with how I installed cmake. I tried reinstalling using homebrew which did not work.

Is there anything I need to do after running the install command?
Could there be another problem?

Comment: Well, this is your error: `clang: error: invalid iOS deployment version '-miphoneos-version-min=11.2', iOS 10 is the maximum deployment target for 32-bit targets [-Winvalid-ios-deployment-target]`

Comment: So if I lower my deployment target to iOS 10.0 will it work? @ACVM

Comment: Well, that's the error it's giving right now. Try it and see if it works, and if not, then we'll check out the next error.

Comment: I changed my deployment target to 9.3 (just to be sure) but it still returns the same error. The clang error you mentioned is still there and it says that my deployment target is still 11.2. Is there something wrong with Xcode? @ACVM

Comment: Do you need to set your cocoapods max target? try adding this line to your Podfile: `platform :ios, '9.3'`.

Comment: I added that line to my code but the clang error is still there and exactly the same. I looked around in my build settings to make sure that the deployment target there was the same, which it was. Do you have any more suggestions? I appreciate your help! ;)